llama3.2 Installation Error: exiting with status 0xc0000135
When I run ollama run llama3.2 after it is installed this error shows up,
llama runner process has terminated: exit status 0xc0000135.
Can anyone tell me the issue.
Using ollama I installed llama3.2 which worked perfectly fine but after that I tried running it and this showed up.

"Can anyone tell me the issue." No i cannot but i can give a guess.

Check logs for other possible errors (might just be corrupted dl or missing dir (if you pointed to different source))

You might want to check if Microsoft visual C++ Redistributable exists, if not install them.


lastly re-install
